# Not selecting a row in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, focus, focusable

I have a JTable with a number of rows, each row made up of a number of JPanels. I want one of the rows in the JTable to be unselectable. I have used a:

```
panel.setFocusable(false);
```

on this particular row. However, when pressing the down arrow key on the table, the selection disappears when it gets to the unfocusable panel. Is there a quick way of skipping the selection all together on this row and just selecting the next row?

Comment: please this is question or complaint, for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JTable/XxxTableModel in local variable

Comment: You override the key bindings for the tables navigation and implement your own keyboard navigation logic. You could implement your own SelectionModel and supply it to the table...

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with help of `ListSelectionListener`. Read more [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html). Simple example:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;


public class TestFrame extends JFrame{
    private int notSelectable = 2;
    private JTable t1;

    public TestFrame(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        init();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
      t1 = new JTable(10,1);
      t1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(getListener());
      t1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
      add(t1);
    }


    private ListSelectionListener getListener() {
        return new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if(t1.getSelectedRow() == notSelectable){
                    if(notSelectable+1 == t1.getRowCount()){
                        t1.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(0, 0);
                    } else {
                        t1.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(notSelectable+1, notSelectable+1);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String... strings) {
        new TestFrame();
    }

}
```

Comment: This works fine for pressing the down key but what about the up key?

Comment: With this, when it selects the row below the unselectable row, it means you can never go back up.

Comment: @maloney seems you need to implement logic for selection direction(up/down), also see suggestion of MadProgrammer